# Passing macro arguments by macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I'm trying to pass a RGB color into a macro that takes three arguments.
A normal call would look like this: `MACRO(255, 255, 255)`
The macro converts the arguments  and together with an operator it is then sent over SPI to a graphics controller. A call in C code looks like this: `cmd(MACRO(0,0,0));`

As the color is used on multiple occasions, but might be subject to change, i thought it might be a good idea to define it via another macro.
So defining a color e.g. `#define BLACK 0,0,0` and inserting it into the other macro should be ok: `MACRO( BLACK )` -> `cmd(MACRO( BLACK ));`
But the compiler outputs an error:

> macro "MACRO" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given

Getting this i assume the macro providing the arguments is not being expanded. I tried to figure out what was wrong reading through the gcc macro documentation, but was not able to sole it. I assume it is one of those stupid simple things...
Thank you!

More info:
There are multiple macros provided by a driver taking three numbers (rgb) as an argument. I would like to define a color scheme to be able to change a color for every occurrence without changing more than those three numbers.

The function where the macro is inserted is taking an unsigned long and that is what the macro is producing.

Why is the term BLACK not simply substituted by 0,0,0?

Quote from the gcc macro documentation:

> "All arguments to a macro are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into the macro body. After substitution, the complete text is scanned again for macros to expand, including the arguments."

Comment: Why do you need to nest anyway? Just use `BLACK` (better add some prefix to make it clear, e.g. `COLOR_BLACK) and use `MACRO(0, 0, 0)` (change the name, e.g. `COLOR_RGB`) inside `BLACK`. More clear and less to type.

Comment: If you have hundreds of RGB-compisition macros, you very likely have done something wrong. Why use a macro anyway? `inline` functions are as fast and much safer. Don't use macros where functions can do the same job.

Comment: @Olaf the function macros are part of a driver i don't want to touch. And i don't want to define a lot of new macros, but just the colors.
The logical point is, that i have several macros provided by the driver and i want to have a defined color scheme consisting of several colors used very often. When i want to change one color in the color scheme i don't want to edit every use of it, but change it in one place, the define macro.

Comment: @nicomp: Disagree with whom? I just ask OP about more information, as this is possibly an XY-problem. So, I do not try to talk him into something without proper analysing his actual problem. If you have more information (e.g. 100+ macros), feel free to provide it! (Btw: what skeaks against "dropping" `inline` functions into a header, too? And the colors might still be macros.

Comment: @HeidiSalami: And that does not work with my first comment - why? Clarify your question!

Comment: @Olaf I hope i undersood it correctly, but that would require to make multiple instances of every color for a variety of different macros that all take a color as argument. The plan was to define every color only once.
I would really love to understand why this is not working. I expect the macro to just replace the code at expansion...

Comment: As I wrote: it smells like bad interface design. But without more information ... Read about how macro arguments are replaced.

Comment: @Olaf as said before, the macros are provided by a driver. I won't touch this. I would simply like to know why the preprocessing is not simply replacing "BLACK" with "0,0,0"

Comment: I think that it replace first the MACRO. So at this moment it found that there is juste one argument.

Comment: @Louis "All arguments to a macro are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into the macro body. After substitution, the complete text is scanned again for macros to expand, including the arguments." That quote from the gcc macro documentation makes it pretty clear the arguments should be expanded first.

Comment: In case it isn't totally clear, the statement "All arguments to a macro are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into the macro body." is not saying that arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into the macro *call*. So `BLACK` is completely macro-expanded only when substituted into the *body* of `MACRO` (which it never gets to, because `MACRO` needs three arguments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to ensure that your combination `MACRO(BLACK)` evaluates the `BLACK` part once more. Otherwise it doesn't "see" the commas separating the zeros. What you could to is rename your existing `MACRO` to `MACRO3` (it receives 3 arguments) and then have

```
#define MACRO(...) MACRO3(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Still don't fully understand why it needs the extra step, but that's working! I tought the arguments were expanded first. Thank you!

Comment: @HeidiSalami, first the thing in `()` is parsed for arguments. You only have one, `BLACK`. Then, `BLACK` is expanded, so now the commas still are part of that one and only argument. When you call `MACRO3` with the expansion of `BLACK`, the separation into arguments is re-done, and then we have 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, got it!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to define your macro like this:

```
#define MACRO(x, y, z) somestuffhere
#define BLACK MACRO(0,0,0)
```

And then call it like that

```
cmd(BLACK);
```

This is a more logical implementation. If you define a macro that take 3 arguments, it should take 3 arguments and not one. However you can call macro inside another macro definition.

Comment: This works, but as i would also like to use the color definition within other macros that is not an optimal solution.